# Change of Font size in SSRS Report header

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Header on my ssrs report, which is written in the expression Box in the Manner:

```
    **="Adventure Works" & vbcrlf & First(Fields!Reporttype.Value, "DataSet1") & vbcrlf & 
First(Fields!ReportName.Value, "DataSet1")**
```

Now from the above, I just need the Adventure Works font a bit higher, how to achieve this in SSRS?

Comment: What do you mean with font higher? You mean larger? Or the line above?

Comment: You can also use HTML to do some formatting within a text box. I personally prefer it over the way Al mentioned. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18748.ssrs-multi-font-color-multi-font-size-within-a-single-field-textbox.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the textbox create two placeholder (expressions), one for the biggest text and other for the smallest.

[image]

For the biggest expression select it an change the `FontSize` in properties to the value you want to.

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks This Helps.. never knew this option of having two expression in the same.